# Yii paginate related data

Tags: php, yii, activerecord

What is the best way to paginate related data in Yii?

For example I may have post and I want to paginate comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be achieved by using code like this, suppose you have `CommentController.php` having:

```
function listComments(){

 /* Write code here to fetch comments with current post from db and 
    return template code via calling renderPartial(). 
    Also implement paging, sorting etc. in this same function.
 */

}
```

After that call this function in action for view post page and pass the comment's listing code in view post template.

Answer (score 0):

Look into [CActiveDataProvider](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CActiveDataProvider) it already has inbuilt pagination support.